# How to create a timeline like the iOS calendar app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am fairly new in Swift(UI) and I am just trying to fiddle around and create myself a timeline like in the Calendar iOS app with the hours on the left and a divider per hour plus a red line where the current time is at.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW2gy.png)

I've seem to accomplish the first (hour and divider), but I am stuck on drawing the current time and position it correctly based on time and spacing.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPxeF.png)

Is anyone able to help me or guide me to the right direction? Thank you in advance!

My current code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    init(){
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    }
    
    var sortedTimeFrom: [Date] = {
        let today = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
        var sortedTime: [Date] = []
        var calender = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        calender.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let currentHour = calender.component(.hour, from: today)
        
        (0...(24)).forEach {
            guard let newDate = calender.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: today),
                  calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) <= 23 else {
                return
            }
            //convert date into desired format
            sortedTime.append(newDate)
        }
        return sortedTime
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical)
        {
            ForEach(sortedTimeFrom, id: \.self) { date in
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text(date, formatter: dateFormatter)
                        VStack{
                            Color.gray.frame(height: 1 / UIScreen.main.scale)
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to check every row for when the hour is equal to now, then calculate the offset based on the minutes & height of each row:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    init(){
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    }
    
    var sortedTimeFrom: [Date] = {
        let today = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
        var sortedTime: [Date] = []
        var calender = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        calender.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        let currentHour = calender.component(.hour, from: today)
        
        (0...(24)).forEach {
            guard let newDate = calender.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: today),
                  calender.component(.hour, from: newDate) <= 23 else {
                return
            }
            //convert date into desired format
            sortedTime.append(newDate)
        }
        return sortedTime
    }()
    var currentDate: (Int, Double) {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: Date())
        let minutes: Double = Double(calendar.component(.month, from: Date()))/60
        return (hour, minutes)
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(sortedTimeFrom, id: \.self) { date in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(date, formatter: dateFormatter)
                            VStack{
                                Color.gray.frame(height: 1 / UIScreen.main.scale)
                            }
                        }
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .frame(height: 30)
                        .overlay(
                            VStack {
                                if Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).component(.hour, from: date) == currentDate.0 {
                                    HStack {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text(Date(), formatter: dateFormatter)
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                            Color.red
                                                .frame(height: 1 / UIScreen.main.scale)
                                    }.offset(y: 30 * currentDate.1)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The hour mark is still off, it's one hour to early on timeline but I can fix this.